# used case for boost make_shared

Tags: c++

I am walking through a cpp code and have the following questions(have almost no exposure to boost library)

```
bool xxxx::calcYYY ()
    {
        bool retStatus = false;
        boost::shared_ptr<DblMatrix> price  = boost::make_shared<DblMatrix>(xxx, xxx); 

.....
            retStatus = true;
        }
        return retStatus;
    }
```

Why are local scoped pointers instantiated as shared?
There must be an additional overhead to maintain reference counting,in a high performing code.
What is the boost alternative to do this correctly here?

Comment: Without seeing more of the function, how can we tell you exactly? Is the pointer passed to some other function? One that maybe is calling something else, that shares ownership? We don't know.

Comment: There's not enough context to say anything. What is `xxx` and `xxx`? What happens in `.....`?

Comment: is `price` stored somewhere or just used and dumped? If it is large and stored somewhere for later use by multiple consumers, then shared_ptr is appropriate. If it is used once and immediately destroyed, then you can simply construct it on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are local scoped pointers instantiated as shared?

Because they point to objects that can be shared. For example, they can be passed to functions that can extend the life of the object they refer to.

> There must be an additional overhead to maintain reference counting,in a high performing code.

Possibly. It's also possible the compiler can optimize it out. There are a lot of tricks, such as passing the pointers by const reference to avoid having to change the reference count, using `std::move` where possible, and so on that can make the additional overhead negligible for many use cases. But, presumably, it's being used because there is some benefit. We can't tell with just the code you've shown.

> What is the boost alternative to do this correctly here?

There is nothing incorrect shown.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are local scoped pointers instantiated as shared?

Because the author wanted to use a smart pointer that would guarantee the memory is freed even if the function exits via an early return, or an exception.

The *best* choice for such a usage is `std::unique_ptr`, but that wasn't available until C++11, and if the original code predates that it wouldn't have been an option.

The next best choice is `boost::unique_ptr`.  That actually handles this case perfectly, but it is in general a lot less useful than `std::unique_ptr` because it didn't support move semantics.  As such, having a general rule "just use `boost::shared_ptr` and stop worrying" is perfectly sensible (particularly if you are going to pass the pointer into  a general purpose function which may want to do reallocation).

There was also `std::auto_ptr` which also handles this case perfectly, but it's going to cause anyone reading the code to go "hang on, is this OK".  It is best just avoided.

> There must be an additional overhead to maintain reference counting,in a high performing code.

If the pointer is allocated once, and then never used until it is released, then the cost of an atomic increment and atomic decrement are going to be lost in the noise of a call to `new` and `delete`.